# Adding options to an options object from outside the object - javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to add a little customisation to a plugin. It has an options object (or it could be called a hash object maybe?) that I want to add more options to from an array.

here is the options object 'itemKeys'

```
   a.extend(a.zEditor.DEFAULTS, {
        itemKeys: {

            "text name 1": "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
            "text name 2": "font-size: 15px; color: black;"
        }
```

I can manually add the key name as an array value

```
key_name = ["text name 1", "text name 2"]

   a.extend(a.zEditor.DEFAULTS, {
        itemKeys: {

            [key_name[0]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
            [key_name[1]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;"
        }
```

But the amount of values in the array will vary so cant manually set it up this way.

Looping through it like so inside the object clearly wont work

```
itemKeys: {
       for (var i = 0; i < key_name.Length; i++) {
            key_name[i]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
           }
        }
```

So now I'm left with making some sort of loop outside of the object that adds new options to the options object. Problem is that i don't know how to even add a new option to an options object from outside the object.

I tried

itemKeys: { "text name 3": "font-size: 15px; color: black;" }

But this just overwrites the object so now it it just has one option in it.

I cant go changing any other coding in the plugin because it will cause other things to break so I'm left with doing it this way.

How can I add more options to the itemKey options object from outside the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.zEditor.DEFAULTS.itemKeys["text name 3"] = "font-size: 15px; color: black;";
```

or, assuming that `a.extend()` works like jquery's `$.extend()`,

```
a.extend(a.zEditor.DEFAULTS.itemKeys, {"text name 3": "font-size: 15px; color: black;"});
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now and you just got it twice! They both work. Which do you think is better? The first is shorter and looks easer for loops. But one might have some sort of random advantage that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Use `a.extend()` as it extends (and not overrides) the object properties. See here, in the console, the output difference: https://jsfiddle.net/89yoduef/1/. I used jquery's `$.extend()` that works like `a.extend()`.

Comment: Hate to ask but now i'm stuck on looping the bloody thing inside the 'a' function. Would appreciate if you could have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876436/how-can-i-integrate-this-for-loop-into-this-function

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble a separate item keys object outside and assign it by reference.

```
var myItemKeys = {};

function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < key_name.Length; i++) {
          myItemKeys[key_name[i]] = "font-size: 15px; color: black;";
    }

}

//Set the itemKeys in the object

a.extend(a.zEditor.DEFAULTS, {
    itemKeys: myItemKeys
...
```