# How can I integrate this for loop into this function

Tags: javascript

Trying to add a little customisation to a plugin.

I have the following loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < key_name.Length; i++) {
  a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS.itemKeys,
           {[key_name[i]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;"});
}
```

I need to run it in this function (or else 'a' won't be defined)

```
function(a) {
    "use strict";
     a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS, {
         itemKeys: {
             [key_name[0]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;"
         }
     }),
     a.ZeEditor.PLUGINS.itemKey = function(b) {...},
     a.ZeEditor.RegisterCommand("itemKey", {...}),
     a.ZeEditor.DefineIcon("itemKey", {...})
});
```

No matter where I put it the 2 most common out comes are either nothing happens (so the coding isn't executed for whatever reason) or I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for`.

I'm thinking I need to add a new function to this coding and put it in there but I cant even find a spot to put the function without an error. or nothing happening
e.g.

```
...
a.ZeEditor.PLUGINS.itemKey = function(b) {...},
a.ZeEditor.RegisterCommand("itemKey", {...}),
a.ZeEditor.DefineIcon("itemKey", {...}),
function KeysLoop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < key_name.Length; i++) {
        a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS.itemKeys, {[key_name[i]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;"});
    }
}
});
```

This doesn't trow an error but also doesn't loop through the array

I'm still learning javascript and this is a bit beyond my knowledge so I need some help.

**EDIT**

Sorry I left some stuff out

key_name is just a simple array 
    `key_name = ["text1", "text2", "text3",]`

The loop is so I don't have to manually put all the array values as the objects option e.g.

```
a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS, {
    itemKeys: {
        "text1": "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
        "text2": "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
    }
```

Also I don't know the array values or how many there are so I need to loop through the array.

This line that is in the for loop works fine when put at the bottom of the function so I know the line works

```
...
a.ZeEditor.PLUGINS.itemKey = function(b) {...},
a.ZeEditor.RegisterCommand("itemKey", {...}),
a.ZeEditor.DefineIcon("itemKey", {...}),
a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS.itemKeys, {[key_name[1]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;"}); 
  // this line ^^
});
```

Comment: What happens when  put a `;` after `a.ZeEditor.DefineIcon("itemKey", {...})` and place your loop afterwards?

Comment: Where to put this for loop..? first of all how did you come up with this loop? where does `key_name`..? If you don't know where to put it, how did you test it and finalized that this is the for loop you need..? You should explain what is going on.

Comment: @TJ Sorry for the lack of info i have update the question

Comment: @user3234020 how do you get access to this `key_name` in the above mentioned function..? You declare it on top..? It doesn't seem to have such a thing as  parameter

Answer (score 0):

Define `function KeysLoop()` outside `function(a){}`, and then call KeysLoop(). Because you are declaring your function but never invoking it.

```
function KeysLoop(a) {
     for (var i = 0; i < key_name.Length; i++) {
        a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS.itemKeys, {[key_name[i]]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;"});
     }
}

 ...
 a.ZeEditor.PLUGINS.itemKey = function(b) {...},
 a.ZeEditor.RegisterCommand("itemKey", {...}),
 a.ZeEditor.DefineIcon("itemKey", {...}),
 KeysLoop(a);
});
```

PD: function names by convention are in camelCase and start with lower case eg: keysLoop()

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It doesn't produce any errors either so im not sure whats going wrong

Comment: Can you paste your whole html with the script in it, and write a line with the expected output please?